# best way to manage a reactjs project and include components

Tags: reactjs

What's the best way to manage components in a reactjs app?  For example, I want to create the following class

```
class Trends extends React.Component {
    // stuff
}
```

Should I create that in a file called `Trends.js` in `src/`?  This is more what I'm used to (java, c#).  Or is the convention to kind of lump things somehow?  I imagine if I have an application with 100's of classes a load of class files would be bad, but so would putting them all in one file (?).

And then secondly, how do I use my `Trends` class?  Include it in `App.js` or should I be referencing that somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, it is common to use a file called Trends.js which contains a Trends component.  Different people will have different opinions on this, but my personal preference is to use the one page standard as much as possible and a clear separation of code between the files.

Comment: There are many ways to structure, there is no right answer. But as per the ReactJS docs the recommended way is this https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html